# Using equals and == for comparisson

Tags: java, operators

I have a condition like this :

```
try {
        History history = requestHelper.getHistory();
       if (!history.getInvoiceNo().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                !history.getCcEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                !history.getHostAuthCode().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                !history.getMerchantCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(null) || //String
                !history.getCcName().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                !history.getCcPhone().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                history.getBatchNo() != 0 || //int
                !history.getIpAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("") || //String
                !history.getTransactionStatus().equals(null)) { //char
            System.out.println(": : : FAILED GET HISTORY, NO PARAMETER SET!");
            requestHelper.getResultHelper().setLstHistoryTransaction(null);
       else {
            System.out.println(": : : SUCCESS GET HISTORY!");
            /* some command */
       }
} catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(": : : ERROR QUERYING HISTORY TO DATABASE");
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

but when i dont fill any variable on that parameters, why it getting error like this :

> 10:07:35,238 INFO  [STDOUT] : : : ERROR QUERYING HISTORY TO DATABASE
>   10:07:35,238 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10:07:35,238 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   doku.edp.executors.ManageTransactionExecutorBean.findHistoryTransaction(ManageTransactionExecutorBean.java:411)
>   10:07:35,238 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   doku.edp.executors.ManageTransactionExecutorBean.execute(ManageTransactionExecutorBean.java:78)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR
>   [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor402.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR
>   [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_613521570.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_613521570.java)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_613521570.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_613521570.java)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>   10:07:35,239 ERROR [STDERR]     at
>   org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)

Comment: please print all `history.` and see what you get... Might that will come to know why you are getting `Null Pointer Exception`

Comment: May I ask what the reason is, to compare an empty String in case insensitve way: `.equalsIgnoreCase ("")`. Btw.: For a long time I haven't seen such an ugly code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest rewriting your `if` statement like this:

```
if (!"".equals(history.getInvoiceNo()) || //String
    !"".equals(history.getCcEmail()) || //String
    !"".equals(history.getHostAuthCode()) || //String
    history.getMerchantCategory() != null || //String
    !"".equals(history.getCcName()) || //String
    !"".equals(history.getCcPhone()) || //String
    history.getBatchNo() != 0 || //int
    !"".equals(history.getIpAddress()) || //String
    history.getTransactionStatus() != null) {
```

There's no point in using `equalsIgnoreCase` when you're comparing to the empty string, and there's no point in using `equals` when comparing to `null`.

Comment: Just use `String.isEmpty()`, no?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Doesn't work so well if the string is `null`.

Comment: Fair enough.  I might go ahead and write an `isNullOrEmpty` in that case...though the use of `null` here is probably a sign that something else is pretty borked.

Answer (score 2):

Never use .equals to check if something null, always use ==

If you want to check if a string is empty or equal to null you should do it like so:

```
//Make sure a string isn't null
if(string != null && string.isEmpty())
```

.equals if used for comparing the value of two objects, so in the case of checking for null you want to use == to check what is being **referenced** by that variable

Comment: thanks for your answer,, now i know when to use equal, when to use ==

Answer (score 1):

I''m guessing that one or more of your `get...` methods are returning `null`.  You need to check for `null` as well as empty strings.

When comparing for null you're doing a reference comparison so

```
somevariable == null
```

is correct.

Comment: I'd add that checking on line 411 of ManageTransactionExecutorBean.java would be a good idea, given the exception stack trace.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin that stack trace come from that file